# Posting File Data to .NET app from kendo-upload using Angular/TypeScript

Tags: asp.net-mvc, typescript, file-upload, kendo-ui

I have a certificate file I need to upload through kendo upload or file select, read the data in the file and post it to MVC application API. I've tried some different ways using file reader and can't seem to get it working. Ultimately, whether it be from vm or dto, I need the certificate converted to byte[] to be saved to db.

html:

```
<div *ngIf="!certificateExists; else addCertificateTemplate">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div style="padding-bottom: 10px">
      <strong>Certificate</strong>
    </div>
    <kendo-formfield>
      <kendo-fileselect
        formControlName="certificate"
        #fileSelect="kendoFileSelect"
        [multiple]="false"
        [restrictions]="fileRestrictions"
        [disabled]="!isEditable"
        (ngModelChange)="onChangeFile($event)">
        <kendo-upload-messages
          select="Select a file to upload"
          dropFilesHere="Drop file here to upload">
        </kendo-upload-messages>
      </kendo-fileselect>
      <kendo-formerror
        *ngIf="
          form.controls?.file?.errors?.required &&
          fileSelect.fileList.files.length === 0">
        Select a file to upload
        </kendo-formerror>
    </kendo-formfield>
  </div>
</div>
```

ts component:

```
handleFormSubmit(): void {
const formValue = this.form?.getRawValue();
if (this.form?.valid) {
  const data = this.form?.value as SomeDto;

  const payload = this.createSubmitPayload(data, formValue);
  this.service
    .save(payload, true)
    .pipe(
      tap((r) => {
        this.onSave(r.id);
      })
    )
    .subscribe();
  } else {
  openExpansionPanels(this.expansionPanels);
 }
}


onChangeFile(files: any): void {
  // I'm not sure what to do here
  const file = files[0];
  console.log(file);
}
```

ts service:

```
save(
  data: SomeDto
): Observable<SomeDto> {
return this.httpClient
  .post<SomeDto>(
    `${API_BASE}/someBaseRoute/save`,
    data
  )
  .pipe(
    this.pageLoaderService.wrapWithLoader(
      'save'
    )
  );
}
```

Vm:

```
public class SomeVm
{
    public type Property1 { get; set; }
    
    public byte[] Certificate { get; set; }
    
    public type Property3 { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("save")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Save(HttpRequestMessage request, [FromBody] SomeVm vm)
    {
        return GetHttpResponse(
            request, () =>
            {
                
                var someDto = new SomeDto
                {
                    Property1 = vm.Property1,
                    Certificate = vm.Certificate,
                    Property3 = vm.Property3
                };

                someDto = _httpClient.Post<SomeDto, SomeDto>("apiRoute/update", someDto).Result;

                return request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, someDto);
            }
        );
    }
```

I'm giving a lot of code context here just to give the full picture. However I'm thinking there's simply some concept I'm missing in the ts component to read the file data.

Comment: How depressing to read your question with no answers. I am working through the same issue. Did you figure anything out?